# Heroku subdomain DNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a Rails app with a custom domain and wildcard subdomains hosted on Heroku (Cedar). Let's call it https://mysite.com.

If a user goes to, for instance, https://bobcat.mysite.com, the Rails app is configured to serve only the data relating to bobcat's account.

bobcat.com is registered with a domain-names company - nothing to do with Heroku. I want to change the DNS settings so that bobcat.com redirects to https://bobcat.mysite.com. What CNAME settings do I use? What do I do on my Heroku account.

Forgive this question which could probably be answered by sufficient googling, but I can't get this wrong...

Comment: When you say "redirects", do you mean you want the user to have the url `bobcat.com` showing while viewing the content of `https://bobcat.mysite.com`?  Just trying to clarify.

Comment: Hi - ideally, yes. But I'd be happy enough for the address bar to say `https://bobcat.mysite.com` after the user typed in `http://bobcat.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**Heroku docs on custom domains**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) holds all info for you.

It's especially important that you set entries for both `bobcat.com` and `www.bobcat.com`, which are in terms of DNS two seperate entries.

For Heroku, the `www.bobcat.com` is handled by a CNAME to `myapp.herokuapp.com`(on the cedar stack).

For "Naked domains" such as `bobcat.com` however no cname can be specified (tue to limitations in the DNS Specifications) so you have two options:

1) Point `bobcat.com` A-Records to the IP-Adresses specified in the docs above.

OR

2) Redirect `bobcat.com` to `www.bobcat.com` using [wwwizer's free service](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect). It's as easy as pointing `bobcat.com` A-Records to `174.129.25.170`. I use this approach in a couple of my projects.

Comment: Thanks for that @thomas-klemm - but do you know how you redirect www.bobcat.com to subdomain.myapp.herokuapp.com, for that is what I want? At the moment I have a CNAME pointing to bobcat.mysite.com, but it only displays mysite.com. Thanks!

Comment: Have you made your app recognize subdomains correctly? The settings there might be a little tricky for it to behave the same with the third-level bobcat.mysite.com and fourth-level bobcat.myapp.herokuapp.com.

Comment: I have no idea, to be honest. The result of `heroku certs` is 

Endpoint: akita-randomnumber.herokussl.com
Common name: *.bobcat.com, bobcat.com

Comment: I meant internal recognition: There's a [`config.action_dispatch.tld_length`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-dispatch) that allows `request.subdomain` to parse correctly. See this stackoverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079586/rails-3-x-tld-length). Could it be that DNS settings are fine but your app parses subdomains incorrectly and thus displays the wrong site for the request?

Answer (score 0):

So I believe, in the DNS settings for the domain name `bobcat.com`, you need to create a new `CNAME` record.

So it would be:

```
Hostname: bobcat.com
Type: CNAME
Destination CNAME: https://bobcat.mysite.com
```

Comment: Per [RFC1033](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1033) CNAME cannot coexist with other records, which means that at the zone apex, since you need SOA and NS records, you can't have CNAME so this won't work. You can try that with BIND; it'll reject it.