# Rails, Devise and Dynamic Subdomains on Subdomain (e.g. user.beta.example.com) how to setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, subdomain, passenger

I'm using basecamp style subdomains, rails 3.2, devise 2, passenger standalone. Everything is working fine on *.example.com. Now i want to launch a staging environment on *.beta.example.com and not sure whats the best way to make it work.

The following method checks if user requests app.example.com (then he is redirected to sign in page) or someone's account (e.g. user1.example.com), otherwise badrequest is returned. (app_subdomain = 'app')

```
def validate_subdomain
  if request.subdomain == Settings.app_subdomain
    redirect_to(user_signed_in? ? users_accounts_path : new_user_registration_path)
  else
    head :bad_request unless current_account?
  end
end
```

If i deploy it to *.beta.example.com then request.subdomain returns "app.beta" and validations no longer work.

What would be the most elegant and reusable way to solve it? Other than to strip environment's subdomain manually. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option one**: change `request.subdomain` to `request.subdomains.first`. Then only `app` from `app.bla-bla-bla.anything.example.com` will be recognized.

**Option two**: set `config.action_dispatch.tld_length` in config/environments/production.rb. Sets the TLD (top-level domain) length for the application. Defaults to 1.

Source on tld_length:

1. [Rails 3.x TLD length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079586/rails-3-x-tld-length)
2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html
3. https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5215-configurable-tld_length-for-subdomains